# angularjs loading different templates for detailed views

Tags: angularjs

I am hoping you can help me.

I am wondering how to do in angularjs a second set of templates.
I have templates for thumbs - now I want to add set of templates for detailed view.

this is how it looks at the moment:

templates are loaded here `<span ng-include="setUrl()"></span>`

and my script looks like this:

```
myApp.directive('contentItem', function () {

    templates = {
      image: 'image.html',
      event: 'event.html',
      article: 'article.html',
      ad: 'ad.html',
      discount: 'discount.html',
      video: 'video.html'

    }

    var linker = function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.setUrl = function(){
          return templates[scope.item.content_type];
        }

    }

    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        link: linker,
        scope: {
          item: '=',
          items: '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'main.html'
    };
});
```

I would like to have views for detailed views:

image-detail.html

event-detail.html

article-detail.html

...

if I will have in submission-full.html

How should I load detailed views?

Live example is here -> [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/nldsOSiat6pLhy1pC8ah?p=preview)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can't you just do `<div ng-include="setURL(template_name)"></div>`?

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more.
I am trying to load for thumb(image.html) a detailed view(image-detail.html)

Answer (score 0):

If your `main.html` looks something like this:

```
<div ng-include="setURL(item.template_name)"></div>
```

Then it will load which template name is specified in the `item.template_name` on the scope, which with your directive should be the `item` given to it. You'll probably have to fix up `setURL` a bit so it returns the actual full path on the server.

Remember that `ng-include` takes an expression not a name. This is why you need a set of extra single quotes in the string when you specify a hard coded template file.